# adding view's to outbound share (the view which is created by union of 2 objects from two different database)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to add the views to an outbound share, but the view is created by referencing to two databases and one of the databases is created from the inbound share.

So when I try to execute the following commands:

```
ALTER VIEW " " SET SECURE;
GRANT REFERENCE ON DATABASE "X" TO SHARE SHARE_A;
GRANT REFERENCE ON DATABASE "Y" TO SHARE SHARE_A;
GRANT SELECT ON VIEW " " TO SHARE " ";

error: Granting individual privileges on the imported databases is not allowed. Use "GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES" instead.
```

But I guess we cannot grant imported privileges to a share right, so what would be the correct steps to add the views?

Comment: This should work as a similar working example is mentioned in the documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-mutiple-db.html#sharing-data-from-multiple-databases

Comment: Does the following not work :
grant imported privileges on database <shared_db> to role <name>;

Answer (score 2):

> ... the view is created by referencing to two databases and one of the
> databases is created from the **inbound share**.

Shared databases and all the objects in the database cannot be forwarded (i.e. re-shared with other accounts).

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-share-consumers.html#general-limitations-for-shared-databases